# Как открыть панель поиска searchControl при size = small|medium?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

parameters.options.size при значениях small и medium строка поиска изначально не отображается https://skr.sh/s9wzp0dlVm2

Поэтому результатов поиска тоже не увидишь, пока не кликнешь на лупу руками https://skr.sh/s9wNgcsliaC

```js
let searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
        size: 'small'
    }
});

myMap.controls.add(searchControl);

searchControl.search('метро').then(() => {
    searchControl.getResult(0);
});
```

Можно ли программным способом сделать так, чтобы панелька с поиском показалась?

Answer (score 1):

Поисковая панель размера small и medium не позволяет открыть себя программно - она не позволяет управлять опцией [noSuggestPanel](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl.html#control.SearchControl__param-parameters.options.noSuggestPanel). Если же вам требуется показать результаты, вы можете просто изменить её размер до large после поискового запроса - выпадет список.

```
searchControl.state.set("size", 'large')
```

Замечу, что со свёрнутой панелью не видно только текстовых описаний результата, сами объекты отображаются на карте- https://c.radikal.ru/c37/2110/3a/27f6e5e11b0b.png.
Если же результат один, открывается ещё и балун-панель с описанием- https://b.radikal.ru/b13/2110/de/9ef3bb91cd30.png

Comment: Ну да, приходится менять размер. Выглядит некрасиво https://skr.sh/sANIaMEg5WC, но хотя бы работает. С выпадающей панелью красиво https://skr.sh/sANZOpXUVTm. Странно, что нет такой возможности.